# jpa-Primarykey relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

Hi created student entity in gogole app engine datastore using JPA.

Student--->Coding

@Entity

@Table(name="StudentPersonalDetails", schema="PUBLIC")

public class StudentPersonalDetails {

@Id

@Column(name = "STUDENTNO")

```
    private Long stuno;
```

@Basic

```
    @Column(name = "STUDENTNAME")

    private String stuname;
```

public void setStuname(String stuname) {

this.stuname = stuname;

}

public String getStuname() {

return stuname;

}

public void setStuno(Longstuno) {

this.stuno = stuno;
 }

public Long getStuno() {

return stuno;
 }

public StudentPersonalDetails(Long stuno,String stuname)
 {
  this.stuno = stuno;
  this.stuname = stuname;
 }

}

I stored Property value as follows

Stuno   Stuname

1         a

2         b

If i stored Again Stuno No 1 stuname z
means it wont allow to insert the record But. It Overwrite the value

Stuno   Stuname

1         z

2         b

How to solve this?

Comment: Please, take some time to format your code properly, this is just unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve what? `stuno` is annotated with `Id`, you can't insert two entities with the same `stuno`. And if you modify an entity that already has a representation in the data sotre (i.e. an entity that has a **persistent identity**), it will get updated. Honestly, I don't get the problem or what result you expect.

Comment: If i entered stuno already exist i will get updated ,I want the i will not  update

Comment: @megala: 1) I think that I gave you a valid hint in my answer. 2) With the current level of details of your question, I can't add anything.